# short cut to view function list in VS2008 which is right under Document tabs

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, function, keyboard-shortcuts

is there a short cut key to view function list in VS2008 which is right under Document tabs

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about VS2008, but I am using VS10x Code Map Add On in my VS2010. Check add ons please. It appear on the left side

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/1c54d1bd-d898-4705-903f-fa4a319b50f2

This is just supported on VS2010, but there should be addons for VS2005 like this addon

Comment: can you suggest any addo on for vs2008